# Simplest tornado.gen example

Tags: asynchronous, tornado

I am trying to use [Tornado's sync-style 'gen' tool](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html) to run a simple echo function, in a non-blocking style:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import logging

def echo(message):
    return message

@tornado.gen.engine
def runme():
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(echo, 'this is a message')
    logging.warn(response)

runme()
```

As far as I can tell this code isn't significantly different to the demo code in the docs, minus the unnecessary request handler stuff - I'm not handling any HTTP requests, AFAICT that's orthagonal to running something asynchronously. Yet this always fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 46, in <module>
runme()
TypeError: wrapper() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Exactly where am I missing the argument? How can I make Tornado run this function asynchronously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task doesn't actually make a callback for the function being run, and start the callback when the function returns, as I originally thought.

I need to create a callback in the task being run myself, and invoke it, i.e.:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import logging

def echo(message, callback=None):
    callback(message)

@tornado.gen.engine
def runme():
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(echo, 'this is a message')
    logging.warn(response)

runme()
```

Comment: What exactly does your code do? since callback is None, wouldn't it raise an Exception on calling echo(message="this is a message", callback=None) ?

Comment: [See the functional description of `Task`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html?highlight=task#tornado.gen). Tornado passes a `gen.Callback` function to `echo`. Beyond that, I'm still trying to figure out myself :)

Comment: It lacks a return, `return callback(message)`. This way it echoes asynchronously when yielding the Task.